# Rails id in db, but without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

In my db i have such field:

```
color_id
```

and in form i use such code, to store it in db:

```
= f.select :color_id, options_for_select([["белый", 1], ["желтый", 2], ["зеленый", 3], ["коричневый", 4], ["красный", 5], ["оранжевый", 6], ["серебристый", 7], ["серый", 8], ["синий", 9], ["фиолетовый", 10], ["черный", 11], ["другой", 12]], :selected => f.object.color_id), {:prompt => "Выберите цвет кузова"}, required: true
```

so i decide to to without model and db table, just id from html form, and this id store in db.

But how to view in show action not it, but color?

I can do it only with if, like:

```
- if c.color_id == 1
  белый
- if c.color_id == 2
  желтый
```

but maybe there is more elegant and good solution? How to change id, to array's color in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define method color, which will put text based on color_id

```
def color(color_id)
  colors[color_id]
end

def colors
  ["name1", "name2"]
end
```

Please note that the array starts from 0, and in your code ids start from 1

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Hash in model having color_id field like following:

```
COLORS = {"1" => "белый", "2" => "желтый",...}
```

And then you can call a method in model for getting the print the color

```
def color
  COLORS[color_id.to_s]
end
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end :COLORS => {"1" => "белый", "2" =>... ^

Comment: That would be due to character encoding. May be mentioning the encoding will resolve this issue, as it works with simple characters.

Comment: in first your code was  =>  must be =, with = is ok